# android EditText onPause in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, onpause, fragment-tab-host

I'm posting this question because I really can't understand what's happening:

I have a tab layout with ViewPager implemented with fragments, everything works very well, but I'm struggling with a really strange behavior: in the onPause fragment's method I need to make some checks on EditText values, but the readen values  from EditText's getText method are not correct: the readen value is the same that I had put in the xml, even if I changed it. So, if in the xml I put

```
android:text="ABCD"
```

and then when at runtime I change this value to "DCBA" or any other value, in the fragment's onPause method the following code

```
((EditText)getView.findViewById(R.id.myEdittext)).getText().toString()
```

always returns "ABCD".

If i run the same code clicking on a button the value is correctly read

Am I missing something???

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to pass in the ID into findViewById?

```
findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text)
```

Edit:

ok, try this instead:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEdittext)).getText().toString();
```

Comment: @SimonVeloper Are you sure the id is correct and you are typing into the correct edit text? try without getView, I updated my answer

Comment: yes,I'm 100% sure, because that is the only EditText I have in that fragment and I can't remove getView because Fragments don't have findViewById method

Comment: Yes it does, as written in the question

Comment: Wait, so, the value of your editText is correct before onPause and after onPause, but it's incorrect during onPause?

Comment: This is so weird. What is the value in onResume?

Comment: it's the (wrong) same, it's the value given in the xml!! How could it be possible??!!

Comment: @SimonVeloper try having a instance variable for your `EditText` and try to `getText()` from the instance variable.

Comment: Maybe the activity stops after pausing for some reason... Does onStop() fire?

Comment: same behavior.. I really don't understand.. :(

Comment: Yes, onPause if fired, but after onPause

Comment: Wait, so onStop() runs? It's not supposed to. If onStop() runs, it might reset your editText to the default xml value

Comment: why onStop should not run? It does, but before the onPause, so nothing should have been destroyed